# run CMD command on windows 10 Universal app Platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

how can i run CMD command on windows 10 (modern) Universal app Platform (UWP) via C#?
i try using this code (it's works on windows form app:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("the command");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

but i have a error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Process' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   OneSpot C:\Users\reuve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\app\app\MainPage.xaml.cs   37  Active
```

and:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context    OneSpot C:\Users\reuve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\app\app\MainPage.xaml.cs   49  Active
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Is that the exact code, or is some of that in a function someplace?

Comment: You simply cannot run executable files in UWP apps.

Comment: the last two codes are the copy of the error.

Comment: this is not a .bat file...

Comment: UWP will include Xbox at some point and I'm pretty confident that you can't start a command prompt on an Xbox.

Comment: i read that you can make a code for PC only:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @ReuvenHerszkowicz Even if you find a way to do that on PC, your app won't get the certificate to be published in Windows Store.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot not launch external executable from your UWP application. This is prevented by the security model.
You are restricted to the methods provided by the [Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx) API.

You can open a file with its default application using [LaunchFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx) or [LaunchUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx). The system will start the application registered by the user to open the file.

Comment: Specific remarks of note: _**"Your app can't select the app that is launched. The user determines which app is launched. The user can select either a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app or a Windows desktop app."**_ and _**"You can't launch file types that contain code or script if they are executed automatically by the operating system, such as, .exe, .msi, and .js files."**_